# Drawing a Wickselian triangle graph in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-arrows, graphs

I am interested in drawing this Wickselian graph using Tikz:

[image]

I want to move the labeling of the figure down below though.

Since I am very new to Tikz any advice on how I can get started?

I would want to be to able to colour the boxes and make them look a bit attractive.

Something the one here:

Comment: Please clarify "make them look a bit attractive".

Comment: @leandriis Never mind. I have figured it out. By attractive I meant using lighter colours such as red!30. But the problem I am having right now is with scaling the graph. I am using this figure on beamer, but if I enter all the information, the information for Betty goes too far to the right and is missing.

Is there a way to make the graph more compact? So that everything is centered in the slide with all the information. Right now I am trying to use \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.50] for the right scaling of the figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following might serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={rounded rectangle,draw=black,align=center},
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex] 
\node[mybox] (Charlie) {\textbf{Charlie}\\ text text text text\\ text text text text};
\node[mybox] (Adam) [below left =of Charlie, fill=green] {\textbf{Adam}\\ text text text text\\ text text text text}edge [->] node[left=10pt,name=CA] {some text} (Charlie) ;
\node[mybox] (Betty) [below right =of Charlie] {\textbf{Betty}\\ text text text text\\ text text text text}edge [->] node[below=10pt,name=AB] {some text} (Adam) edge[<-] node[right=10pt,name=BC] {some text} (Charlie) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

another starting point ... used are `arrows.meta`, `positioning`, `quotes`, `shadows` and `shapes.misc` TikZ libraries:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadows, shapes.misc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
           node distance = 18mm and 9mm,
              box/.style = {rounded rectangle, draw=#1, thick, fill=#1!30, 
                            align=center, drop shadow},
       every edge/.style = {draw=gray, -Triangle, line width=1.2mm,
                            shorten >=1mm, shorten <=1mm},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, align=center}
                        ]
\node (Charlie) [box=red]               {\textbf{Charlie}\\
                                         text text text text\\ text text text text};
\node (Adam)    [box=blue, 
                 below left=of Charlie] {\textbf{Adam}\\
                                         text text text text\\
                                         text text text text};
\node (Betty)   [box=green,
                 below right=of Charlie]    {\textbf{Betty}\\
                                         text text text text\\
                                         text text text text};
\path   (Charlie)   edge ["some\\ text"] (Betty)
        (Betty)     edge ["some\\ text"] (Adam)
        (Adam)      edge ["some\\ text"] (Charlie);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(as starting MWE is used @leandriis answer)

[image]